# Center text inside automatically generated label tag

Tags: html, css

I get the following snippet of html from a CMS:

```
<label title="">
    Land
    <input id="Land" name="Land" size="20" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Land" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</label>
```

I need to center the text `Land`, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried setting `text-align: center` on the label, but it doesn't work. I can't modify the markup. Is it something simple I'm missing?

EDIT:
I want to center it over this input:

[image]

Don't mind the right edge of the input field. The `label` span 100% of the width of the input field.

Comment: What do you mean? Center it where?

Comment: Ah, sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to deal with that .

1.The display property specifies if/how an element is displayed so label must be displayed as block or inline-block to center it

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

2.you can use html tag center

```
<center>
  <label title=""> 
     Land
     <input id="Land" name="Land" size="20" type="text" value="">
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Land" data-valmsg-  replace="true"></span>
  </label>
</center>
```

And if you want to center the word Land over the centered Label , you can just add this

```
<center>Land</center>
```

Comment: Used the first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

the  tag is an inline element and therefore exactly the same width of its content.

You would need a div or something to do this

Doing this without  being able to alter the markup itself would be messy at best and will probably consist of some javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

the label is not expanding on 100% width because it's an inline element. to enable this - set on the label css:

```
label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

or insert the text directly into a block element like: div, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
Simply add the following CSS to achieve the desired result:

```
label input, label span {
    display: block;
}
```

See a live demo: http://jsbin.com/sebinuje/1/edit?html,css,output OR http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_agarwal/5yUQr/

---

Enclose the snippet with a div element and apply the text-align property on the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="label-enclosure">
<label title="">
    Land
    <input id="Land" name="Land" size="20" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Land" data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#label-enclosure{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: @KheemaPandey - The question was differently framed earlier and my answer was specific to that version. I have updated the answer to reflect the change in question.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm loath to recommend using a `<br/>` tag here is one way given your current structure

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5P2B/)

**HTML**

```
<label title="">
    Land
    <br/>
    <input id="Land" name="Land" size="20" type="text" value=""/>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Land" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```